# Google.Protobuff timestamp.proto in c#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I have successfully compiled my .proto file with google.proto.Timestamp and generated the .cs file with protoc. The only problem i am having is initialization in my c# code.

I have tried the following:

**.proto File**

```
message teststamp
{
    string Name = 1 ;
    string address = 2;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp _timeStamp = 3;
}
```

**C# File**

```
teststamp test = new teststamp();
test.Name = "Test";
test.address = "Test_Test_TEST"
//Example 2 : POSIX
test._timeStamp.Seconds = DateTime.Now.Second;
test._timeStamp.Nanos = DateTime.Now.Second*1000 ;
```

The above is compiling without errors but giving me this error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` .I have tried few other approaches but due to less help it is unable to fix the error.

Please help me out in this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timestamp is class so you have to create it first like this:

```
test._timeStamp = new Timestamp() { Seconds = DateTime.Now.Second }
```

Answer (score 37):

Most people will probably just want to use the helper methods:

```
using Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes;

var timestamp = Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow)
```

Comment: +1 if you have a DateTime instance: var timestamp = Timestamp.FromDateTime(_mydatetime.ToUniversalTime())

Comment: Simply: var birthday = Timestamp.FromDateTimeOffset(new DateTime(1973,12,25));

Answer (score 21):

Full example for anyone.
More info [Official documentation about Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/timestamp)

Proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Test";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

package OnlineGrpc;
service OnlineGrpcService {
  rpc SendMessage(SendMessageRequest) returns (SendMessageResponse);
}
message SendMessageRequest{
    google.protobuf.Timestamp requestDate = 1;
}

message SendMessageResponse{
    google.protobuf.Timestamp responseDate = 1;
}
```

C# send request

```
var request = new SendMessageRequest();
request.requestDate = DateTime.Now.ToTimestamp();
request.requestDate = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToTimestamp();
```

C# read response

```
var response = new SendMessageResponse();
DateTimeOffset dateOffset = response.responseDate.ToDateTimeOffset();
DateTime date = response.responseDate.ToDateTime();
```

Comment: C# request return Conversion from DateTime to Timestamp requires the DateTime kind to be Utc (Parameter 'dateTime'). I think we need to convert DateTime.Now to UTC and then .ToTimestamp()

Answer (score 5):

Here's my attempt to convert an existing DateTime instance to Timestamp:

```
// doc.CreateOn is a DateTime 
Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind(doc.CreatedOn, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone stumbles across this post.

Here's a code example:

```
var unixTimeMS = DateTimeOffset
    .UtcNow
    .ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

var seconds = unixTimeMS / 1000;
var nanos = (int)((unixTimeMS % 1000) * 1e6);

var lul = new ProtoModel
{
    Timestamp = new Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp()
    {
        Seconds = seconds,
        Nanos = nanos
    }
};

var unixTimeMSBack = lul.Timestamp
                .ToDateTimeOffset()
                .ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```